# How to retrieve a collection with advanced orderBy?

Tags: php, laravel, sql-order-by

Scenario: I want to search Mercedes, but I forgot how to spell "Mercedes", so I typed "mer", and the dropdown result show me "Nissan Almera" on the top, because "Almera" contain "mer" and the id of "Nissan Almera" is smaller than "Mercedes", then I have to scroll until very bottom only can see the result of "Mercedes".

```
public function getCarModel(Request $request) {
    $term = $request->term;

    $arr = explode(' ', $term);
    $results_collect = [];

    foreach($arr as $key => $str) {
        $model_results = car_models::with('brand')
        ->whereHas('brand', function($q) use($str){
            $q->where('brand', 'LIKE', '%'.$str.'%');
        })
        ->orWhere('year', 'LIKE', '%'.$str.'%')
        ->orWhere('model', 'LIKE', '%'.$str.'%')
        ->orWhere('spec', 'LIKE', '%'.$str.'%')
        ->orWhere('engine', 'LIKE', '%'.$str.'%')
        ->pluck('id');

        $results_collect[$key] = $model_results->toArray();   
    }

    $results_intersect = collect($results_collect[0]);
    foreach ($results_collect as $collect) {
        $results_intersect = $results_intersect->intersect($collect);
    }

    $models = car_models::with('brand')->whereIn('id', $results_intersect)->take(100)->get();
    $auto_complete_results = [];
    foreach ($models as $key => $model) {
        $auto_complete_results[$key] = (object) [
            'value' => $model->id,
            'label' => $model->year.' '.$model->brand->brand.' '.$model->model .' '.$model->spec.' '.$model->engine,
        ];
    }

    return response()->json($auto_complete_results);
}
```

This is how the database looks like

id | brand_id | model | spec | engine | year

1, 6, Almera, VL, 1.5, 2017

2, 6, Almera, E, 1.5, 2014

3, 13, A, 180 Urban Line (CBU), 1.6, 2017

brand_id 6 = Nissan

brand_id 13 = Mercedes-Benz

If the user type "mer" this function will always return 3 record and sorted by id which is (1,2,3). The output that I expect is (3,1,2), because I want the output show the brand result first then only follow by model, spec, engine, and year.

Comment: `->orWhere('model', 'LIKE', $str.'%')` As long as you know you are using the first few letters

Comment: That doesn't sound difficult, just do multiple orderBys, in the order of importance.

Answer (score 0):

In **brand** search, please replace code with this as  `$q->where('brand', 'LIKE', $str.'%');`
Because you want your search key should return result which will be in start of the response,not over all in the response.

```
public function getCarModel(Request $request) {
        $term = $request->term;

        $arr = explode(' ', $term);
        $results_collect = [];

        foreach($arr as $key => $str) {
            $model_results = car_models::with('brand')
            ->whereHas('brand', function($q) use($str){
                $q->where('brand', 'LIKE', $str.'%');
            })
            ->orWhere('year', 'LIKE', '%'.$str.'%')
            ->orWhere('model', 'LIKE', '%'.$str.'%')
            ->orWhere('spec', 'LIKE', '%'.$str.'%')
            ->orWhere('engine', 'LIKE', '%'.$str.'%')
            ->pluck('id');

            $results_collect[$key] = $model_results->toArray();   
        }

        $results_intersect = collect($results_collect[0]);
        foreach ($results_collect as $collect) {
            $results_intersect = $results_intersect->intersect($collect);
        }

        $models = car_models::with('brand')->whereIn('id', $results_intersect)->take(100)->get();
        $auto_complete_results = [];
        foreach ($models as $key => $model) {
            $auto_complete_results[$key] = (object) [
                'value' => $model->id,
                'label' => $model->year.' '.$model->brand->brand.' '.$model->model .' '.$model->spec.' '.$model->engine,
            ];
        }

        return response()->json($auto_complete_results);
    }
```

Hope this will help you.